# Spring MVC: After exception also 200 OK response

Tags: spring-mvc

I have below controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="fetchprofilepics/{profileId}/{column}/{random}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void fetchProfilePhoto(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String profileId, @PathVariable String column, @PathVariable String random) throws IOException, ContentDeletedException
{
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
    try {
        //.............

        bufferedOutputStream            = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        ByteBuffer          byteBuffer  = imgService.getProfilePhoto(cqlSession, column, profileId);
        if(byteBuffer==null) throw new ContentDeletedException();
        byte                bytes[]     = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];

        byteBuffer.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        bufferedOutputStream.write(bytes);
    } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    finally{if(bufferedOutputStream!=null) bufferedOutputStream.close();}
    throw new ContentDeletedException();
}
```

if `byteBuffer` is `null` it throws `ContentDeletedException` in tomcate log but in browser console it still show `200OK` response. So in client side its showing empty image.

Why? It should not throw `200 OK` status.

Comment: ContentDeletedException is not marked with @ExceptionHandling or you have web.xml config for error?, but it seems exeption is being throw and catch in your try catch block

Comment: `ContentDeletedException` is being thrown in tomcat console.`IOException` is not thrown

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I am doing this:

```
if(byteBuffer==null){
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
}
else{
    byte  bytes[]     = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];            
    byteBuffer.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    bufferedOutputStream.write(bytes);
}
```